# Recurring debit/credit card payments via PayPal without PCI compliance

Tags: php, paypal, recurring-billing

Developing a site that requires monthly subscriptions via PayPal. If a buyer has an account this is no problem via ExpressCheckout. The client has a (UK-based) Pro account though and wants to provide the option of payment by card.

As far as I can work out from the 'Website Payments Pro Integration Guide' this requires setting up a dual payment option on my site, giving the user the option of paying 'via Paypal' (ie ExpressCheckout) or by card, at which point my site would provide a PCI compliant card capture form that would submit to PayPal using DirectPayment. Going through PCI compliance isn't really an option. It seems weird that PayPal doesn't offer a hosted solution for this, or am I just being stupid?

TL;DR: Is it possible to process recurring card payments via PayPal in the UK using a PayPal hosted card capture form?

Site is bespoke PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PayPal API [allows for recurring payments](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPRecurringPayments#id08669F0705Z) with Direct Payment:

> Recurring payments with Direct Payment enables a recurring payment to
>   be associated with a debit or credit card.
>
> [...]
>
> The CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile response contains a Profile ID,
>   which is an encoded string that uniquely identifies the recurring
>   payments profile.

PayPal holds the account number and other pertinent information (including billing frequency) while your application stores the Profile ID.

PCI compliance is never an *option*. It is always a requirement. However, the rules for compliance are far less stringent (including forgoing auditing) for companies that don't perform a high volume of transactions per year.

Comment: I've already seen this and indicates a 'no', but you would think PayPal would be able to do this. It returns the Profile ID so it wouldn't have to do anything extra in the back end.